# How can i resolve Azure Pipeline Build Error?

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, pipeline

I am running build pipeline for my REST API. I have upgraded my version to .net6.0. Below is my error:

> The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 6.0.  Either target .NET 5.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 6.0.

Below is a part of my yaml for api:

```
 - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'publish'
        publishWebProjects: true
        zipAfterPublish: true
        arguments: '--output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/api'
```

Kindly help me and let me know in case of any more details:

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved. I had to add new step in my yaml and tell it to use/set the target framework .net6.0.x

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: Use .NET 6.0
      inputs:
          packageType: 'sdk'
          version: '6.0.x'
          installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet
```

Adding the above step in my yaml resolved both the errors.

Thank You :)